# Крестьянин и христианин (ряд ударения)

Tags: орфоэпия

Заинтересовал этот вопрос. В книге «Звоним русисту» (между прочим, очень полезная книга) сказано, что в слове *христианин* ударение падает на последний слог. По строению слово очень похоже на *крестьянин*, ударение в котором, как говорится в Википедии, падает на Я. Возможно ли ударение на И? Другой пример ряда слов: жонглёр, контролёр и т.п.

Comment: С октября 2013 г. этот вопрос обсуждался шесть раз.

Comment: Почему «Звоним русисту» очень полезная книга? «Другой пример ряда слов: жонглёр, контролёр» как связан с вопросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В слове "христианин" ударенбие действительно падает на последний слог.
христиани́н, -а; мн. христиа́не, -а́н [не христиа́нин]

См.:Русское словесное ударение: Словарь. Зарва М.В.  - Около 50 000 слов. - М.: Изд-во НЦ ЭНАС, 2001. - 600 с.

Как видите, в словарях дается ударение на последним слоге. Ударение на ***и*** в этом слове невозможно.

Comment: Небольшое добавление из ОСРЯ-10 (под ред. Н.А. Еськовой): в 18-19 веках ударение *было* на а, христиа́нин.

Comment: А можно привести оригинальный текст (фрагмент) статьи?